# Is it possible to disable file download in chrome using selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

On visiting some pages using ChromeDriver and Selenium, downloading of a particular file is happening automatically. Because of the file download, the code is not proceeding further. Is it possible to disable downloading of file using any ChromeOptions or preferences that can be set while creating ChromeDriver.

Tried the following ChromeOptions, but none helped.

```
prefs.put("download.default_directory", "NUL");
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 0);
```

Comment: do you mean a window pops up, like save as ?

Comment: @ChandlerBing I do not want anything to be dowloaded. Just disable automatic downloading of file. On setting the pref 'download.prompt_for_download' to true, i see the file save dialog appearing. But what i want is, I do not want the file to be dowloaded at all.

Comment: Can you get me an example of a site which downloads automatically? Thanks

Comment: @Dev its an internal site actually. Won't be able to share it.

Comment: @Sarath So what are you expecting when you simply try to hit a download link like this (http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0.zip) ? Thanks

Comment: @Dev I am not clicking on any download link. The moment i land on the page (eg., www.google.com), a file is starting to download. I want to skip/block this automatic downloading of file. Is there any capability that i can set in Selenium to achieve this?

Comment: @Sarath There are certain options available but you need to guide me with a sample URL which does that. Thanks

Comment: @Dev we have an internal app, www.stage.cr.com. The moment i open the page using ChromeDriver (manually also), an apk file will start to download automatically. How to avoid this from downloading at all.

Comment: @Sarath Do you mean the google analytics sites? e.g. gstatic.com, google-apis.com ?

Comment: @Dev No. Its an internal site.

Comment: @Sarath If you can point me to a demo website then I can provide you a solution. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB  I know this is a bit old, but I am encountering the same issue. When visiting the link to the static document below, chromedriver will save the file to my download folder. Is there a way to avoid this default behavior ?

https://www.hudoig.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2016-FW-1007.pdf

Comment: @LeoBouloc Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thank you, I posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491516/disable-all-downloads-with-chromedriver-and-selenium

Comment: @Sarath did you managed to solve this? I literally tried every solution in the internet, none of them worked!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but you can try this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("download.prompt.for.download",false);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

In chrome **'Allow Download Restrictions'** has the following 4 options:

- 0= No Special restrictions
- 1= Block dangerous downloads
- 2= Block
  potentially dangerous downloads
- 3= Block all downloads
- 4 = Block malicious downloads

**Code:**

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
 prefs.put("download_restrictions", 3);
 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

#Ref: https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DownloadRestrictions

Comment: for reference see here https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DownloadRestrictions