# Disable all downloads with ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When accessing some static files such as [hudoig.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2016-FW-1007.pdf](https://hudoig.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2016-FW-1007.pdf) (random example) with Selenium using ChromeDriver, the file is automatically downloaded to my default download directory.

Is there a way to disable this default behavior and prevent files from being saved ? Thank you.

NB: My question is similar to the following unanswered question but in my case I actually want to disable downloads even when clicking download links: 
[Is it possible to disable file download in chrome using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144502/is-it-possible-to-disable-file-download-in-chrome-using-selenium?noredirect=1#comment105157019_44144502)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Preferences for ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Set-a-Chrome-preference) are an experimental options.

You could set download preferences explicitly and have PDF documents opened directly in the Chrome browser.

For example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
    "download.open_pdf_in_system_reader": False,
    "download.prompt_for_download": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": False
}
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", prefs
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)
driver.get(
"https://www.hudoig.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2016-FW-1007.pdf"
)
driver.close()
```

Or you could set the download location to write the document to a virtual device file as `/dev/null` effectively discarding it.

For example:

```py
prefs = {
    "download.open_pdf_in_system_reader": False,
    "download.prompt_for_download": True,
    "download.default_directory": "/dev/null",
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": False
}
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", prefs
)
```

You could set download restrictions to [block all downloads](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DownloadRestrictions).

```py
prefs = {
    "download_restrictions": 3,
}
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", prefs
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. For the first solution, this only partly covers my problem as I am looking for a solution that would block local downloads for all extensions.

As for the second solution (/dev/null), I believe that the file is still fetched fully. Is there a way not to download in the case of files being written to disk ?

Comment: You could set `download_restrictions` option to block all downloads. I was made aware of this option from natn2323 answer. Other configurable options can be found in chrome://prefs-internals

Comment: Thank you. This last answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that you could take would be disabling the browser's ability to download. Namely, configure the `DownloadRestrictions` policy, discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1289493/how-do-i-disable-download-in-google-chrome).